# excel vba how to know if a user performs an autofill and force it to xlFillCopy?

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

Well almost everything is in the title.

I know how to perform an autofill with the code.
I know how to catch a lot of events and actions performed by the user on a sheet.

But here the challenge is to catch that the user has performed an autofill on few cells on a sheet, and then force the autofill to xlFillCopy instead of xlFillSeries...

Any idea?

Comment: see what you can do with this: http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/08/15/vba-excelallow-paste-special-only/

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the Worksheet Change event and then examine the last action in the undo list:

```
If Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1) = "Series" then
...
```